# How to construct a pattern in java regex that checks whether there is a decimal in the given number

Tags: java, regex

I've searched all of stackoverflow for this which seems like a basic question but nothing is working for me. I am trying to implement an if else with this condition 
`if(Pattern.matches("-?[.]?[0-9]+?", currentDisplayText))` everything else works fine in this but it doesn't even acknowledges the decimal, i've also tried using `if(Pattern.matches("-?\\.?[0-9]+", currentDisplayText))`but still doesn't works

edit: Sample data i'm trying to match 23,-23,23.1,-23.1 it works with all of them except the ones with decimal in it like 23.1 or -23.1, the problem is how do I input the decimal in regex pattern

Comment: Can you show us sample data which you are trying to match?

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html says `-?.?[0-9]+` will match, but note you only have one set of digits, so it matches .3 not 0.3

Comment: @John3136 can you give me a pattern that matches 0.3

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you are looking for: `"-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?"`

1. optional '-'
2. 1 or more digits
3. optional group of a . followed by 1 or more digits

Comment: @SebastianProske True. I was trusting http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html too much. But of course the string "." matches the regex "." ;-) standby for an edit.

Comment: This is what i figured out `-?\d+(\.\d)*` thanks for your help!

Comment: @SakshamShridhar Just remember to escape those "\" if you use them in a java string. Also "*" means 0 or more matches ,so -1.2.3.4 will matches your regex (and it probably shouldn't)